# Understanding `Boolean.constructor` and `Boolean.constructor(true)`

Tags: javascript, prototype

Looking at the `Boolean.constructor`:

```
var bool = true;
var booleanObj = new Boolean(true);
console.log ('typeof bool', typeof bool);             # returns 'boolean'
console.log ('typeof booleanObj', typeof booleanObj); # returns 'object'
```

The following line returns:  `function Function() { [native code] }`. How can I see the `native code`?

```
console.log('Boolean.constructor', Boolean.constructor);
```

Lastly, how can I get

```
var y = Boolean.constructor(true);
console.log('typeof y', typeof y); # returns function
```

Then, printing `y` gives: `y: function anonymous() { true }`. How can I extract `true`?

```
console.log('y:', y);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9YxkE/

Answer (score 1):

`Boolean` is a function.

Its `constructor` property is the constructor for all functions; namely, the `Function` function.

The native code is part of the Javascript engine and is typically written in C++.
If you want to, you can explore the source code for V8 or SpiderMonkey.

`true` is the body of the function you created by calling the `Function` constructor.